# expand an environment variable in zsh command prompt dynamically

Tags: zsh, prompt, zshrc

I'd like a prompt in zsh which is showing the actual state of a certain environment variable. 
Right now I am using the below method, but it is evaluating the variable only once when zsh is started up and when the value of the variable changes the prompt remains the same. Is there a way to make it dynamic?

```
export PROMPT="[${THE_VAR}]"
```

Comment: Had figured this one out in the meantime based on [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11877551/zsh-not-re-computing-my-shell-prompt)